# How to display scroll bar in angular material mat-select on safari?

Tags: html, css, angular, safari, angular-material

This is a browser specific issue. In chrome, firefox and edge the scroll bar is displayed when there are more [mat-options](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)  than the [mat-select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) can display. The user knows there are more options because of the scroll bar. In safari however, the scroll bar only appears when the user scrolls down. This means the user might not be aware there are more mat-options in the mat-select. Here is some example code:

```
<mat-select>
  <mat-option>
    Option 1 
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option>
    Option 2 
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option>
    Option 3 
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option>
    Option 4 
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option>
    Option 5 
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option>
    Option 6 
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

How can i force the scroll bar to be displayed always on safari like the other browsers? The user might not know Option 6 exists otherwise in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Try to forcefully show it on hover

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(100,100,100,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: What about on touch devices...there is no hover.

Comment: Tried, work on safari but not on mobile. Even setting this style directly (which does not require the user to hover to trigger it) doesn't work.